# Get all IPV4 connected vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get all IPV4 from my lan connection with my router, but I just receiving my own.

Is there an API to do that ?

Here is what I tried:

```
 Sub GetIps()
    Dim adapters As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    Dim adapter As NetworkInterface
    For Each adapter In adapters
        Dim properties As IPInterfaceProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
        If properties.UnicastAddresses.Count > 0 Then
            For Each unicastadress As UnicastIPAddressInformation In properties.UnicastAddresses
                Dim ip As IPAddress = unicastadress.Address
                If ip.AddressFamily = AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                    MsgBox(ip.ToString)
                End If
            Next unicastadress
        End If
    Next adapter
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot get _**other**_ devices' connections to the router (if that's what you're asking) because your computer is not aware of them. Only the router itself has that kind of information, and I'm 99.9999% sure that there isn't an (easy) way to obtain it.

Comment: Easiest way to do this simply ping the whole IP Range

Comment: I suspect that the only other way would be to write code that logs into your router's settings and parses the page that shows which computers are connected.